# How often are user tags updated?

Tags: support

This is the Prolog tag in my profile:

[image]

It says I have 13 posts. But when I click it, there are 19 posts:

[image]

I know that they are not updated immediately, but I've made some posts 5 days ago and they still not appear on these tags.

How often are the tags in a user's profile updated?

Comment: The script is currently stuck. *Normally* it is once a day at 03:00 UTC, but it hasn't run for 5 days in a row now and last time it did run no badges were awarded.

Comment: Also see [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226681)